# Make sure at least one record check box is checked in GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView in an ASP.Net page with an id of GridView1 in which I have a checkbox in first column. Sample code is given below.

When I click on the button having an id of btnSubmit, then I want to make sure that at least one check box is checked in the gridview.

**How would I do this using jQuery?**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
   <HeaderTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" ToolTip="Click here to select/deselect all rows" runat="server" />
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  //other columns follow
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server> />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use a class for your checkboxes in your ItemTemplate. Now I will give solution in both the contexts.

This will give you the info that if atleast 1 checkbox is checked. But this is a generic way. Better add a class for the gridview also if you are writing this JS in external JS file.

```
$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID%> input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length>0
```

If you have applied class for both the GridView control(grdMyGrid) and checkboxes("chkMyCheckBox").

```
$('.grdMyGrid .chkMyCheckBox:checked').length>0
```

This is much simpler and recommended way. You can use the above statements in your IF clause or assign the result in a variable for later use.

Comment: The first expression throws an error. It should be $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID%>  input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length. No need of adding javascript concatenation operator, since the server side tag for client will be automatically replaced at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

you can get all `checkboxes` in `GridView1`, and then check if its contains any checked element:

```
var hasAnyChecked = $("#GridView1 input[type = checkbox]").is(":checked")
```

also you can try to get all checked element, and then go for **`length`**

```
var hasAnyChecked = $("#GridView1 input[type = checkbox]:checked").length != 0
```